# Firefox addonsdk sandboxing and require API

Tags: javascript, firefox, sandbox, firefox-addon-sdk, require

I have a firefox addon-sdk. I created a test add-on similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started

Now in my main.js I do something like this

```
const { XMLHttpRequest } = require('sdk/net/xhr');

var fooLibrary = require("foo");
```

Where `foo` is a module that provides some functionality using XMLHttpRequest

The problem is now when I try to run some function inside `fooLibrary` I get an error that says 
`"XMLHttpRequest is not defined"`

I have learnt that when I load a module inside my add-on using the `"require"` API it gets loaded in a sandbox that is created for my module.

My question is how can I set the `XMLHttpRequest` API in a global scope so that my foo library can simply call

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() ?
```

Any help on this subject would be extremely helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global scope. You need to `require` `XMLHttpRequest` in `foo.js`.

Comment: That's exactly right. See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK) for a full explanation.

Comment: Thank you guys! That seems to work just fine. I can't believe I didn't try that before.